# Are all player characters in Gamma World expected to wear armor?

Tags: armor, gamma-world, gamma-world-7e

I'm looking over the rules for Armor in the Gamma World 7e Core Book on page 72.  It states that light armor, which grants a +3 bonus to AC still allows you to move around, and indicates no penalties.  Heavy armor grants an enormous +7 to AC and only reduces movement by one.

Does the math behind the system in Gamma World expect that all players will wear armor of one sort or another?

Is there any mechanical reason not to wear armor as a player character?

Comment: Based on your answer, when you asked if it's expected that all players will take light armor, do you actually mean to ask whether players are expected to take *any* form of answer, or *at least* light? As is, if sounds like you're asking if players are expected to wear light and not heavy.

Comment: Good point Jonathan.  I updated the question to be more clear that I'm asking if it's expected that all players will wear armor.

Comment: Ok, this makes more sense. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking over how AC is calculated, I may have answered my own question.

Looking at ability score generation on page 59, if you have two origins that both have the same primary ability score of either Intelligence or Dexterity, then you'd have a modifier of 5 for that ability which would give  your character a fairly low AC of 15 when compared against Gamma World monsters or DnD 4e PCs (a valid comparison due to the relation of the two systems).

If your two primary attributes don't match, but one of them is int or dex then your modifier would be 4 for an AC of 14 - even lower.

So it seems that yes, system is expecting everyone to take armor of some sort to bring ACs up by 3 or 7 points (plus one more of you go with a shield).